# How the "this" affected in a method's method?

Tags: javascript

I am study the udacity's course and encounter a problem.

https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs255/l-49464373/e-73862317/m-73162952

```
function xhrGet(reqUri,callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", reqUri, true);
    xhr.onload = callback;

    xhr.send();
}

var TILEDMapClass = Class.extend({

    // Boolean flag we set once our map atlas
    // has finished loading.
    fullyLoaded: false,

    //-----------------------------------------
    // Load the json file at the url 'map' into
    // memory. This is similar to the requests
    // we've done in the past using
    // XMLHttpRequests.
    load: function (map) {

        // Perform an XMLHttpRequest to grab the
        // JSON file at url 'map'. We've provided
        // the xhrGet function from the optional
        // unit for you to use if you want.
        //
        // Once the XMLHttpRequest loads, set the
        // 'fullyLoaded' flag to true.
        //
        // YOUR CODE HERE
        xhrGet(map, function(){
            this.fullyLoaded = true;
        });
    }

});

// We define a single global instance of our
// map for the rest of our game code to access.
var gMap = new TILEDMapClass();
```

the link says that it use `gMap.load.apply(gMap, [jsonURL]);`
http://forums.udacity.com/questions/100058023/scope-of-this#cs255

but I think that inspite the fact using the called mothod.(The load will belong to gMap)

But because

```
xhr.onload = function(){
                this.fullyLoaded = true;
            }
```

is a method belong to the xhr object,

and the `this` is inside an an anonymous function

the `this` should reference the xhr not gMap.

Why the `this` reference gMap?

Answer (score 2):

*this* is funny within closures. You have to remember that the this keyword will usually refer to the owner of the method. Usually the caller (window for global functions) but when a method is called as a property of an object, this will refer to the object itself.

See this: "this refers to the parent object inside function code if the function is called as a property of the parent." [Understanding this](http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/)

The rules directly from [Understanding this](http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/):

- By default, this refers to the global object.
- When a function is called as a property on a parent object, this
  refers to the parent object inside that function.
- When a function is called with the new operator, this refers to the
  newly created object inside that function.
- When a function is called using call or apply, this refers to the
  first argument passed to call or apply. If the first argument is null
  or not an object, this refers to the global object.

Comment: But the execution should be called by xhr.load()? Then why this isn't pointered to xhr?

Comment: When a function is called using call or apply, this refers to the first argument passed to call or apply. If the first argument is null or not an object, this refers to the global object. In this case, gMap.load.apply(gMap, [jsonURL]); passes gMap as the first object. It gets tricky but apply is there for this reason

Answer (score 1):

`this` doesn't necessarily mean the function or object it's being called on, if you're used to using jQuery and are confused by this, the jQuery methods actually set `this` on all of its functions for convenience by calling one of these two functions which set `this` to the caller:

```
call(object, arg0, arg1...);
apply(object, args[]);
```

So basically, unless the function is setting `this` by calling one of the above functions, it will be set to some outer function/object or `window`.

Answer (score 1):

"this" in a javascript function has nothing to do with the object to which the function *belongs*, but what object it is executed *against*

Contrast with Java, where those are the same because a method is truly part of an object and cannot exist without one (not considering statics).

For example:

```
var blah = {
  test: function () {
    console.log('test');
  }
};
var f = blah.test;
var bleh = {
  test: blah.test
}
```

If I then make each of these three function calls, what is "this" pointing to in each call?

```
blah.test();  // this points to blah
f();          // this is null (or undefined, not sure which)
bleh.test();  // this is bleh
```

I can also use Function.call to call a function object in the context of any object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

```
f.call(window);  // this is window
```

Understanding "this" is difficult when working with callbacks because the callback function is usually invoked by some other library (like jquery for instance) and their API may or may not make a guarantee to what "this" refers to.  What you can do as a work-around:

```
someAsyncFunction(function () {
  bleh.test();
});
```

That will ensure the function you care about is called with a predictable "this" reference.