# JavaScript prototype function call

Tags: javascript

This is PhoneGap application, but I think it is irrelevant here. So here is code I am using:

```
function Geolocation(){

    this.maximumAge = 3000;
    this.timeout = 20;
    this.enableHighAccuracy = true
    this.geolocation = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.onSucess, this.onError, {maximumAge : this.maximumAge, timeout : this.timeout, enableHighAccuracy: this.enableHighAccuracy});
}

Geolocation.prototype.onSucess = function(position){
}

Geolocation.prototype.onError = function(error){
    alert( typeof this.onSucess );
}
```

and whenever onError is triggered this alert returns `undefined`. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `this.onError` is not called with the right context. You can try `Function.bind()`:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    this.onSucess.bind(this), 
    this.onError.bind(this),
    //...
```

The same goes for `onSuccess`.

Comment: This is correct answer! I will mark it soon. Thanks! Does it have any "side effects"?

Comment: Nope, except that some browsers needs a shim for `Function.prototype.bind` (like IE8-). You’ll find more info and code here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that success is spelled wrong, there is no way to be certain yet.

The tricky thing about JavaScript's use of "this" is that "this" is not determined by the method's definition but by how it is invoked.

I explained this recently in another similar question:

[How the "this" affected in a method's method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165052/how-the-this-affected-in-a-methods-method/19165235#19165235)

For example, I can define a variable that points to your function:

```
var blah = this.onSucess;
blah();  // "this" will be undefined

var bleh = {
  test: this.onSuccess
}
bleh.test();  // "this" will be the object literal.
```

When getCurrentPosition calls your callback function, it probably just calls it directly:

```
onSuccess(position);
```

therefore "this" is not defined.

What you can do is pass it a wrapper/proxy function that has a closure reference back to your Geolocation object so it can call this.onSuccess:

```
function Geolocation(){
    this.maximumAge = 3000;
    this.timeout = 20;
    this.enableHighAccuracy = true
    this.geolocation = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
          this.onSucess(position);
      },
      function (error) {
          this.onError(error);
      },
      {
       maximumAge : this.maximumAge,
       timeout : this.timeout,
       enableHighAccuracy: this.enableHighAccuracy
      });
}
```

A short-hand way to do this, as shown by David, is to use Function.bind, which returns a wrapper function doing just what I described, like so:

```
function Geolocation(){
    this.maximumAge = 3000;
    this.timeout = 20;
    this.enableHighAccuracy = true
    this.geolocation = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.onSucess.bind(this),
      this.onError.bind(this),
      {
       maximumAge : this.maximumAge,
       timeout : this.timeout,
       enableHighAccuracy: this.enableHighAccuracy
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*this.onError* is running in another context. it is running in context of *navigator.geolocation*.

If you want to run *this.onError* in context of *Geolocation*, you have to use a proxy method like this:

```
proxy = function(func, context) {
     func.apply(context);   
}
```

usage:

```
proxy(this.onError, this)
```

as example see this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z32BZ/

have a nice day :-)